# Running a deep learning TTS in 2019 using (DeepVoice | WaveNet | etc)

Tags: deep-learning, text-to-speech

I'm attempting to convert a series of sentences in a txt file to WAV files in as clear a voice as possible.

According to a [2019 survey](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/a-2019-guide-to-speech-synthesis-with-deep-learning-630afcafb9dd) there are many recent advancements using deep learning techniques.

Which is great news, because the built-in or commonly used text-to-speech engines sound very robotic.  (OSX's "say" command, espeak, etc).

The problem is, the github pages or collab notebook links are focused on how to train a new model, or set up a docker instance, and don't seem to include a minimum

```
git clone ...
./speak "How are you doing?" -o hayd.wav
```

Do you know how to install and run any of the 2019 engines from that article to speak a sentence?

I'll update if/when I find one that works.

Comment: trying to understand this myself :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about any of the others in the list, but for WaveNet you can use Google's [API](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/apis). Your code sends the text to Google, and they return the audio. There are [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) available for C#, Go, Java, Node.js, PHP, Python, and Ruby. If you want to do it from another language you could use the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/). For WaveNet, the first 1 million characters per month are free. After that it is $16 per 1 million characters. See their [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/pricing).

If your project is a relatively small one-off and you are not bothered about doing it programatically (it wasn't clear from the question), then you could just use their [online demo page](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/) and use a browser add-on (e.g. [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) or one of many others) to download the results as audio files. Alternatively you could use the API on the [command line](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol).

The quality of WaveNet is in my opinion, excellent, and is a vast improvement over the previous generations of text-to-speech algorithms. You can *almost* believe the voices are real at times.

Comment: I did this - was easier than getting anything running locally, and lots of free calls to get started.  :/ . Grudgingly accepting this answer (I wish it was easier to run stuff locally!)